# Is textarea a required field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I'm building a large form that will compile tour schedules of our clients (comedians). [Seen here.](http://www.standupexperts.com/avails-test2.html)

Whenever I delete the larger textarea at the bottom, the form stops work, ie. the submit button doesn't do anything.

Anyone why that might be happening? Thanks.

I don't know exactly what would be helpful, but here's the code for the div containing the form:

```
<div class="info-avails">       

<form action="http://www.standupexperts.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post" name="hgmailer" >
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="adam@standupexperts.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="FormMail E-Mail">

                    <p> Name:<span style="color:white">X-</span>  <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="">
                    <span style="color:white">X.X</span>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" value=""><br />
                    Cell #: <span style="color:white">X.</span><input type="text" name="cell" size="20" value="">
                    Address:<span style="color:white">X</span><input type="text" name="address" size="30" value=""><br />
                    Website: <input type="text" name="website" size="20" value="">
                    Video Link:<input type="text" name="videolink" size="30" value=""><br />
                <!--    Tell us about your event. <br />  <textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea> <br /> -->


                    </p>

            <div class="avails-method">
    <h3>
    Our avails method
    </h3>

If you cannot use the form below, you can <a href="mailto:adam.comedycaravan@gmail.com">email your schedule</a>. Use our notation system if you want your avails entered sooner.    

<a href="http://www.mediafire.com/file/wqyo8tpwq536048/2013_Comedy_Caravan_Avails_Sheet.doc">
                    Download</a> our 2013 avails sheet.
                    <br /><br />
For routing purposes, we want to know the dates you are NOT available and what state you'll be on those dates. <br /><br />

Below, <em>an X is already placed on open/available weeks</em>. For booked dates, please enter days booked and the state.

Example:<ul>
    <li>12-3: X (open)</li>
    <li>12-10: X 11-14 NC (open except the 10th thru 14th of Dec in NC)</li>
    <li>12-17: 19 OH, 22 IN (open except for the 19th of Dec in OH and the 22nd in IN)</li>
    <li>We are unable to work with <em>just</em> the day of the week (3/11: Thurs-Sun)</li>
    </ul>

                    </div> 
        <br class="clear" />                
    <h4>
    2013 Avails/Schedule
    </h4>


    <div class="year2013">
        <div class="jan-apr">

    1/07: <input type="text" name="1/07__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    1/14: <input type="text" name="1/14__" size="20" value="X"><br />    
    1/21: <input type="text" name="1/21__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    1/28: <input type="text" name="1/28__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    2/04: <input type="text" name="2/04__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    2/11: <input type="text" name="2/11__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    2/18: <input type="text" name="2/18__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    2/25: <input type="text" name="2/25__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    3/04: <input type="text" name="3/04__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    3/11: <input type="text" name="3/11__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    3/18: <input type="text" name="3/18__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    3/25: <input type="text" name="3/25__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    4/01: <input type="text" name="4/01__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    4/08: <input type="text" name="4/08__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    4/15: <input type="text" name="4/15__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    4/22: <input type="text" name="4/22__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    4/29: <input type="text" name="4/29__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    </div>
    <div class="may-aug">
    5/06: <input type="text" name="5/06__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    5/13: <input type="text" name="5/13__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    5/20: <input type="text" name="5/20__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    5/27: <input type="text" name="5/27__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    6/03: <input type="text" name="6/03__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    6/10: <input type="text" name="6/10__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    6/17: <input type="text" name="6/17__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    6/24: <input type="text" name="6/24__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    7/01: <input type="text" name="7/01__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    7/08: <input type="text" name="7/08__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    7/15: <input type="text" name="7/15__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    7/22: <input type="text" name="7/22__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    7/29: <input type="text" name="7/29__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    8/05: <input type="text" name="8/05__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    8/12: <input type="text" name="8/12__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    8/19: <input type="text" name="8/19__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    8/26: <input type="text" name="8/26__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    </div>
    <div class="sept-dec">
    9/02: <input type="text" name="9/02__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    9/09: <input type="text" name="9/09__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    9/16: <input type="text" name="9/16__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    9/23: <input type="text" name="9/23__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    9/30: <input type="text" name="9/30__" size="20" value="X"><br />
    10/07: <input type="text" name="10/07__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    10/14: <input type="text" name="10/14__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    10/21: <input type="text" name="10/21__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    10/28: <input type="text" name="10/28__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    11/04: <input type="text" name="11/04__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    11/11: <input type="text" name="11/11__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    11/18: <input type="text" name="11/18__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    11/25: <input type="text" name="11/25__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    12/02: <input type="text" name="12/02__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    12/09: <input type="text" name="12/09__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    12/16: <input type="text" name="12/16__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    12/23: <input type="text" name="12/23__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    NYE:<span style="color:white">..</span>   <input type="text" name="NYE__" size="19" value="X"><br />
    </div>
    </div><br class="clear" /> 
    <div class="commentsection">
    Anything else you want to add?<br />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="hgsubmit();" >
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.standupexperts.com">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh Sorry. I think this is what you are asking about:

<script type="text/javascript">
function hgsubmit()
{
if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.name.value) == false) alert ("Please provide your name.");
else if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false) alert ("A valid email address is required.");
 else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) alert ("Your email content is needed.");
  else {
       document.hgmailer.submit();
       alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
       }
}

Comment: @AdamWhite Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: your type attribute is wrong.it should be submit.

Comment: @raminomrani The JavaScript submits the form. Having `type="submit"` would send the form twice, one without validation.

Comment: Simple, the _name_ of the text box at the bottom of the linked page is "comment".  In the JS you have posted, there is a check on the comment field - [ else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) 
  alert ("Your email content is needed."); ] Simply comment-out this check. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false)
   alert ("Your email content is needed.");
```

If you remove the textarea from the form, `document.hgmailer.comment` no longer exists, and therefore its `.value` causes an error. So, if you want to delete the textarea, you must also delete this check from your JavaScript.

Comment: else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) alert ("Your email content is needed.");
  else {
       document.hgmailer.submit();
       alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
       }
}

To make the edit you are referring to, do I just need to delete that last "else if" instruction?

DELETE ALL OF THIS:
else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false) alert ("Your email content is needed.");
[/END DELETE}

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the formmail.pl expects a comment field without which the submission fails validation and is ignored.

Now ideally you would modify the formmail.pl to make this comment field optional. You can also remove the text area and replace it with a `<input type="hidden" name="comment" value="" />` field, that will include an empty comment field with every submission.

<strike>###*Somewhat off-topic*###
On the surface this setup does not look very secure to me. Without adequate security, this form could end up being abused by spammers. The main issues are that the target email address is sent from a hidden variable which spammers can easily modify. The subject as well as the contents are also coming from the form. Unless the formmail.pl has some anti-spam measures, and those are configured correctly, you would do well to either add the security or use a different script.</strike>

Never mind that, I checked and it only emails local addresses so very little chance of spam.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm a little out of my element. Can you recommend a better way to proceed. I know there are form mail services out there, but this won't be used so much that it warrants spending $9.95/mo. There are free versions of some forms that would work, but they usually have a field limit.

Comment: I edited my comment to reflect the state of your current script - you don't have any spam issues to worry about.

Comment: FIXED! It worked when I deleted that "else if" command. Thank you all for your invaluable assistance. Very much appreciated. Now I need to start teaching myself javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In the html above, if you change the submit button `<input>` from button to submit.it wouldn't halt.also try this in `firebug` or chrome `element inspector`.

change

```
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="hgsubmit();" >
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="hgsubmit();" >
```

also edit javascript to prevent twice server requestion.let the html mark up do the stuff.

Comment: do you have chrome installed?

Comment: I use Chrome, but I haven't tried firebug yet. The script works, but I want the textarea to be optional. I'll try element inspector.